# Combining two objects into one object and sorting by timestamp

Tags: javascript, laravel, object, vue.js

In Laravel, I have used this approach to combine to collections together and returning as one collection.

```
$collection = $messages->merge($texts)->sortByDesc('created_at')
```

If I `dd($colection)`, it shows Collection object all combined and sorted together.

Then I tried to send it to vue via ajax, however, the data is separated again. So my object looks like this:

```
item: {
   messages: [
      0: { ... }
      1: { ... }
      2: { ... }
      3: { ... }
   ],
   texts: [
      0: { ... }
      1: { ... }
   ]
}
```

this is because `return response()->json('item' => '$collection')` separates them as messages and texts again.

---

I tried combining them like this, but it overwritten the values (I assume because ids are same).

```
vm item = this;

// in response of ajax get,
.then(function(response) {
   var item  = response.data.item;
   Object.assign(vm.item.messages, vm.item.texts);
});
```

What is the right way to combine texts into messages and sorting them by timestamps? They all have created_at in the first level of objects like this:

```
messages: [
   0: { created_at: ... }
],
texts: [
   0: { created_at: ... }
]
```

---

Update: After icepickle's answer, with concat, I was able to combine them in messages array. Now, I have an issue for created_at values as they are converted to strings. Here are some test data. This is what I got after ordering:

```
messages: [
   0: { 
     msg: 'hello',
     created_at: "2017-10-12 00:48:59"
   },
   1: { 
     msg: 'mellow',
     created_at: "2017-10-11 16:05:01"
   },
   2: { 
     msg: 'meow',
     created_at: "2017-10-11 15:07:06"
   },
   4: {
     msg: 'test'
     created_at: "2017-10-11 17:13:24"
   }
   5: {
     msg: 'latest'
     created_at: "2017-10-12 00:49:17"
   }
],
```

Comment: Is maintaining the keys in the objects important? If not, try `Object.values` on both of them (returning an array of the values in the object) then you can append them to each other and sort it.

Comment: All I want is sorting them out and combining them under `messages` array. However, I couldn't figure out how to utilise `Object.values`. Can you please expand it?

Comment: `item.messages.concat(item.texts).sort(function(a, b){ return a.created_at - b.created_at; })`

Comment: @destoryer only, that this doesn't create a new array, but expands messages with the text items, and then sorts that array, depending what might still happen with messages, it could be an unwanted side effect

Comment: Unwatnted side effect like mis-ordering?

Comment: @senty No, unwanted side effect that item.messages will now contain the texts as well, so you are mutating your response, which could theoretically be used at another place at a later time still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't it be enough to [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat?v=a) the arrays, and then sort?

A bit like

```
let result = ([]).concat(item.messages, item.texts);
```

or in es6

```
let result = [...item.messages, ...item.texts]
```

and then calling sort on the result

```
// in place sort, result will be sorted, and return the sorted array
result.sort((a, b) => a.created_at - b.created_at);
```

```js
const items = {
  messages: [
   { 
     msg: 'hello',
     created_at: "2017-10-12 00:48:59"
   },
   { 
     msg: 'mellow',
     created_at: "2017-10-11 16:05:01"
   },
   { 
     msg: 'meow',
     created_at: "2017-10-11 15:07:06"
   }
  ],
  texts: [
   {
     msg: 'test',
     created_at: "2017-10-11 17:13:24"
   },
   {
     msg: 'latest',
     created_at: "2017-10-12 00:49:17"
   }
 ]
};

let result = [...items.messages, ...items.texts].sort((a, b) => new Date(a.created_at) - new Date(b.created_at));
console.log( result );
```

Comment: It works nicely except the ordering part. It is not ordering as created_at ascending or descending. They are mixed with random timestamps :/ Do you have any idea what may cause that?

Comment: Like this: 2017-10-12 00:48:59

Comment: @senty, so strings?

Comment: Yes, they are converted to string

Comment: @senty any chance you could add some properties to your question? So there is some test data available?

Comment: I have added some data. It is ordered somehow but not according to a pattern. Do you think the reason is that they are strings?

Comment: @senty Yeah, transforming them to `Date` definitely helped ;)